# Trigger Error 1326 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, cursor, database-trigger

I'm having a problem creating a trigger in MySQL. My "tb_pessoa" table stores my users' data. I would like that when a new insert is made, it stores in the "tb_email" table the user's email, checking if it already exists, but when performing the query with the cursor, it says that the cursor was not opened, and it was. What can it be?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `db_agenda`.`tb_pessoa_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `tb_pessoa` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    declare id_email, id_tipo_email int(11);
    declare nm_email varchar(100);
    declare cr_email cursor for
    select id_email, nm_email, id_tipo_email
        from tb_email
            where nm_email like new.nm_email;
    declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000'
  open cr_email;
  lp_email: loop
    fetch cr_email into id_email, nm_email, id_tipo_email;
    if (id_email = null) then
      insert into tb_email set
        id_email = (select max(id_email)+1 from tb_email),
        nm_email = nm_email,
        id_tipo_email = 1;
        close cr_email;
        leave lp_email;
    end if;
  end loop lp_email;
  close cr_email;
END
```

Comment: Is `id_email` an auto-increment column?

Comment: No, it's inserted by max(id_email)+1 of a subquery

Comment: Why don't you change it to auto_increment? Then it will do that automatically.

Comment: because if I remove one row, the counter continues always, and I don't want this happens

Comment: That's a bad reason. If you remove a row in the middle you'll get a gap, what's wrong with having a gap if you remove the last row?

Comment: really, there's nothing wrong, tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a cursor, just execute an `INSERT` that gets the values from a `SELECT`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tb_pessoa_AFTER_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON tb_pessoa
ON EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO tb_email (nm_email, id_tipo_email, id_email)
    SELECT e.nm_email, 1, @id_email := @id_email + 1
    FROM tb_email AS e
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id_email := MAX(id_email) FROM tb_email) AS i
    WHERE e.nm_email LIKE NEW.nm_email
```

Also, if `NEW.nm_email` doesn't contain any wildcard characters `%` or `_` you should use `=` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: The only thing I will have to do is a subquery with the max()+1 of the id_email

Comment: If you do that you'll use the same `id_email` in all the rows that are added. I've updated the answer to show how to increment it for each row inserted.

Comment: one more question, why do you used a Cross Join?

Comment: The subquery just iniitalizes a variable, there's no column that relates it with the `tb_email` table. `CROSS JOIN` is used when there's a cross-product with no relationship.